# What is the Python Version installed

Tags: python, windows

With Windows 10, I installed Anaconda3 4.1.1

Under Programs & Features, it shows

```
Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda3 4.1.1 64bit).
```

In a cmd prompt, I typed `python --version` and it shows

```
**Python 3.4.4** :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

So, is my Python installation 3.4 or 3.5?

Comment: Go into your shell and type `import sys; sys.version`.

Comment: You probably have *both* installed.

Comment: [Related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/505081/what-version-of-python-do-i-have)

Comment: In "Programs & Features" you see 3.5.2. Is it the only version you see there?

Comment: zondo - this is the output from what you said to try:

'3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'

In Programs&Features, if I type 'Python', in the search box, I see only what I posted.

Answer (score 2):

You have both versions in your computer.

In your path environment variable, the python version referred is 3.4.

Comment: Another responder said to type import sys; sys.version, below is the output.  Shouldn't I see both version listed here?

'3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'

Comment: @user3043799, you don't say how you ran Python for the second test. If you ran `python --version` and got 3.4.4, and then from the same command prompt ran `python` to get the interactive shell and `sys.version` was for 3.5.2, I'd be perplexed, but chances are that's not what you did.